# Java Images not loading in gui

Tags: java, image, awt

Here's some simple sample code I made for this question. When I run the code it is just blank. Other gui things work fine, but images do not load. Yes, my pictures are in a .gif format and are in the correct folder. I am using eclipse, but it does this with all compilation methods. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class test extends Applet
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Image pic = getImage(getCodeBase(), "hare.gif");
        g.drawImage(pic, 10, 10, 160, 120, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `Applet`, at least us `JApplet`, or better yet, a `JPanel` and then add that to what ever top level container you want. Applets have a bunch of "requirements" that make learning difficult. 2. Don't override `paint`, especially of top level containers, instead, override the `paintComponent` method of  a `JPanel` and make sure you are calling the `super` method to maintain the appropriate paint chain

Comment: 3. *"Yes, my pictures are in a .gif format and are in the correct folder"* - Then `getImage(getCodeBase(), "hare.gif")` isn't going to help you, as the images are not stored on the web server, but are embedded within the Jar file itself.  Consider using something like `BufferedImage pic = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("hare.gif"));` assuming that the image exists within the same directory as the `test` class

Comment: So is there no way to display images with the applet class? While more efficient methods are good, is there any way to do it with the code I have without restructuring it?

Comment: `BufferedImage pic = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("hare.gif"));`

Answer (score 0):

The method description (in netbeans) starts by saying "Invoked by Swing to draw components. Applications should not invoke paint directly, but should instead use the repaint method to schedule the component for redrawing. This method actually delegates the work of painting to three protected methods: paintComponent, paintBorder, and paintChildren."

Maybe an alternative could be adding a JLabel and using setIcon to display an image?

Comment: While this is true and valid advise, it doesn't answer the question of why the images aren't loading. And applet doesn't have a paintComponent method